# Make a progress bar for an ongoing request in Python

Tags: python, request, pyqt, pyqt4, python-requests

My application makes quite often requests to a certain webpage to fetch some json file. I do this through requests library and everything is working well.

The problem is that it would be nice to have an indicator (progress bar, ideally) which shows how long it is going to take until the data is requested & loaded.

Is there any way to achieve this?

P.S.: I'm using PyQt4 framework to develop my app (and hence, the progress bar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the load time is fairly short (i.e. just a few seconds), the simplest thing to do would be to show a [busy/wait cursor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#CursorShape-enum):

```
QtGui.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor)
# retrieve network resource ...
QtGui.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
```

or set it on some specific widget:

```
somewidget.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.BusyCursor)
# retrieve network resource ...
somewidget.unsetCursor()
```

Comment: Indeed, this seems like the simplest and most elegant solution, not sure how I didn't think of that one >.>.

Answer (score 0):

1. pick some random number (ie 30 second)
2. get the current timestamp (start_time)
3. download whatever and show a timer for the number above
4. get the current timestamp (end_time)
5. next time you download instead of using your random number above use the start/stop times from the actual download ...

Comment: I was actually thinking of doing something like this (more like, keeping track of last 5 download speeds and averaging them). Problem is... it's not really accurate. Sometimes the request takes about 2 seconds to complete, other times it's 0.5 second.

Comment: yes that is a problem ... but in my experience this is the best you can do for effort vs reward

Comment: In the end this is just a niche design to let users know "hey, i'm doing something, wait for me to finish up". Can you suggest me some other (than progress bar) common way on how you let the users know to wait? Currently I click button and there is no change until everything has been requested and processed. However, because it is quite fast (2-3 seconds max usually), I don't want to clutter the GUI with unnecessary pop-ups or such.

Comment: you could always just put up some spinny thing ... usually when I do this method its for much longer than 2 or 3 seconds ...